# Why produce the canvas rendering an empty image file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

My goal:

If the Camera button on my site is clicked > open the smartphone Camera > take a picture from a qr-code > resize it with js > load the picture on my server > read the qr-code > give me the value from the qr-code back.

My problem is that my code produce an empty image file(jpg) and gives me an error.

I tested it with uploading a existing qr-code image and it works on the second try to upload it. On the first try i get the same error like if i try to upload the taken picture from the smartphone.

my html

```
<form id="qr-code-upload-form" class="form-group" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>
        <span id="qr-pic" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
        <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput" style="display: none;">
    </label>
    <canvas id="cnvsForFormat" width="400" height="266" style="display:none;"></canvas>
</form>
```

my js/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("change", "#cameraInput", readCode);

    function readCode() {
        var cnvs=document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");
        var input = document.getElementById('cameraInput').files[0];
        var img = new Image();
        if (input) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                //Get the input image file

                img.src = e.target.result;

                var newHeight = img.height/2;
                var newWidth = img.width/2;

                //reduce the size until its lower than 600px
                while (newWidth>600 || newHeight>600) {
                    newHeight = newHeight/2;
                    newWidth = newWidth/2;
                }
                $("#cnvsForFormat").attr("height",newHeight);
                $("#cnvsForFormat").attr("width",newWidth);

                //Draw the input image in a canvas with the right size for the upload
                var ctx=cnvs.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, newWidth, newHeight);
                var resizedImg = cnvs.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                //Send the resized Image to my php-request-file
                $.post("?cmd=ajax&param=qr_verarbeiten",{photo:resizedImg},function(e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input);
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

my php to read the qr-code

```
if (isset($_GET['param']) && $_GET['param'] == "qr_verarbeiten" && isset($_POST['photo'])) {

$img = base64_decode(substr($_POST['photo'],23));

file_put_contents("img/upload/qr.jpg", $img);
$qrcode = new QrReader("img/upload/qr.jpg");
echo $qrcode->text(); 
}
```

I use jQuery, Bootstrap and SMARTY in that project

I really hope somebody can help me!

Thanks for taking time to read this and i apologize for my bad english.

The problem was in the js. And i've added the js/MegaPixImage Libraray to handle the big files i get from the iPhone Camera - The working code is :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("change", "#cameraInput", readCode);

    function readCode() {
        // var cnvs=document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");
        var input = document.getElementById('cameraInput').files[0];
        if (input) {
            var img = new Image();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                img.onload = function() {

                    var count=0;
                    while (img.width<1) {
                        count++;
                    }

                    var newHeight = img.height;
                    var newWidth = img.width;

                    while (newWidth>600 || newHeight>600) {
                        newHeight = newHeight/2;
                        newWidth = newWidth/2;
                    }

                    var renderImg = new Image();
                    var mpImg = new MegaPixImage(img);
                    mpImg.render(renderImg, { width: newWidth, height: newHeight });

                    $.post("?cmd=ajax&param=qr_verarbeiten",{photo:renderImg.src},function(e) {
                        alert(e);
                    });
                };
                img.src = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was cause the browser load the img.src asynchron. So i have to add an img.onload function before i load my img.src to make sure the img is already rendered. ;-)

I've added the working code to my question.